# Enviar imagen al fondo (detras del texto) y poner borde solido de color

Tags: vba

Estoy realizando una macro que me inserte imagenes en power point (Este punto esta listo), pero necesito que las imagenes queden en el fondo (por detras de las letras) y tengan un borde solido de color, aun no logro realizar esta accion.

Les adjunto el codigo.

```
Sub ajustar2()


'imagenes diapo 3'

Set imagen1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(3)
imagen1.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\SUR\1.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=10, Top:=50, Width:=220, Height:=128
    
Set imagen2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(3)
imagen2.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\SUR\1_V.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=235, Top:=50, Width:=231, Height:=128
    
Set imagen3 = ActivePresentation.Slides(3)
imagen3.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\SUR\1_D.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=470, Top:=50, Width:=231, Height:=128
    
Set imagen4 = ActivePresentation.Slides(3)
imagen1.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\SUR\2.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=10, Top:=218, Width:=220, Height:=128

Set imagen5 = ActivePresentation.Slides(3)
imagen2.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\SUR\2_V.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=235, Top:=218, Width:=231, Height:=128

Set imagen6 = ActivePresentation.Slides(3)
imagen3.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\SUR\2_D.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=470, Top:=218, Width:=231, Height:=128
    
'imagenes diapo 4'

Set imagen1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(4)
imagen1.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\SUR\3.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=10, Top:=50, Width:=220, Height:=128
    
Set imagen2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(4)
imagen2.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\SUR\3_V.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=235, Top:=50, Width:=231, Height:=128
    
Set imagen3 = ActivePresentation.Slides(4)
imagen3.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\SUR\3_D.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=470, Top:=50, Width:=231, Height:=128
    
Set imagen4 = ActivePresentation.Slides(4)
imagen1.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\SUR\4.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=10, Top:=218, Width:=220, Height:=128

Set imagen5 = ActivePresentation.Slides(4)
imagen2.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\SUR\4_V.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=235, Top:=218, Width:=231, Height:=128

Set imagen6 = ActivePresentation.Slides(4)
imagen3.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\SUR\4_D.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=470, Top:=218, Width:=231, Height:=128
    
'imagenes diapo 5'

Set imagen1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(5)
imagen1.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\SUR\5.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=10, Top:=50, Width:=220, Height:=128
    
Set imagen2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(5)
imagen2.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\SUR\5_V.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=235, Top:=50, Width:=231, Height:=128
    
Set imagen3 = ActivePresentation.Slides(5)
imagen3.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\SUR\5_D.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=470, Top:=50, Width:=231, Height:=128
    
Set imagen4 = ActivePresentation.Slides(5)
imagen1.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\SUR\6.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=10, Top:=218, Width:=220, Height:=128

Set imagen5 = ActivePresentation.Slides(5)
imagen2.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\SUR\6_V.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=235, Top:=218, Width:=231, Height:=128

Set imagen6 = ActivePresentation.Slides(5)
imagen3.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\SUR\6_D.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=470, Top:=218, Width:=231, Height:=128
    
'imagenes diapo 6'

Set imagen1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(6)
imagen1.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\NORTE\7.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=10, Top:=50, Width:=220, Height:=128
    
Set imagen2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(6)
imagen2.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\NORTE\7_V.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=235, Top:=50, Width:=231, Height:=128
    
Set imagen3 = ActivePresentation.Slides(6)
imagen3.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\NORTE\7_D.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=470, Top:=50, Width:=231, Height:=128
    
Set imagen4 = ActivePresentation.Slides(6)
imagen1.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\NORTE\8.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=10, Top:=218, Width:=220, Height:=128

Set imagen5 = ActivePresentation.Slides(6)
imagen2.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\NORTE\8_V.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=235, Top:=218, Width:=231, Height:=128

Set imagen6 = ActivePresentation.Slides(6)
imagen3.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\NORTE\8_D.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=470, Top:=218, Width:=231, Height:=128

'imagenes diapo 7'

Set imagen1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(7)
imagen1.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\NORTE\9.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=10, Top:=50, Width:=220, Height:=128
    
Set imagen2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(7)
imagen2.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\NORTE\9_V.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=235, Top:=50, Width:=231, Height:=128
    
Set imagen3 = ActivePresentation.Slides(7)
imagen3.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\NORTE\9_D.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=470, Top:=50, Width:=231, Height:=128
    
Set imagen4 = ActivePresentation.Slides(7)
imagen1.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\NORTE\10.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=10, Top:=218, Width:=220, Height:=128

Set imagen5 = ActivePresentation.Slides(7)
imagen2.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\NORTE\10_V.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=235, Top:=218, Width:=231, Height:=128

Set imagen6 = ActivePresentation.Slides(7)
imagen3.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\NORTE\10_D.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=470, Top:=218, Width:=231, Height:=128

'imagenes diapo 8'

Set imagen1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(8)
imagen1.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\NORTE\9.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=10, Top:=50, Width:=220, Height:=128
    
Set imagen2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(8)
imagen2.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\NORTE\9_V.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=235, Top:=50, Width:=231, Height:=128
    
Set imagen3 = ActivePresentation.Slides(8)
imagen3.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\NORTE\9_D.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=470, Top:=50, Width:=231, Height:=128
    
Set imagen4 = ActivePresentation.Slides(8)
imagen1.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\NORTE\10.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=10, Top:=218, Width:=220, Height:=128

Set imagen5 = ActivePresentation.Slides(8)
imagen2.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\NORTE\10_V.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=235, Top:=218, Width:=231, Height:=128

Set imagen6 = ActivePresentation.Slides(8)
imagen3.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\INFORMES\DIARIO\NORTE\10_D.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=470, Top:=218, Width:=231, Height:=128
    
 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Para cada diapositiva:

```
Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(8)
For Each sh In myDocument.Shapes
    sh.SendBackward
    With sh.AddLine(10, 10, 250, 250).Line

        .DashStyle = msoLineSolid

        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 0, 128)

    End With
Next
```

Mirar a ver, ya nos dices, no lo puedo probar ahora mismo